# Java JPMS: `package xxx is not visible`

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I have a simple Java project using the non-modularized dependency "io.prometheus:simpleclient_hotspot:0.16.0". It has been working fine until, for other reasons, I wanted to use the Java module system and add a `module-info.java` to my project. Once I do that, I start getting the compilation error:

```
error: package io.prometheus.client is not visible import io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry;
                    ^   (package io.prometheus.client is declared in the unnamed module, but module simpleserver does not read it)
```

The prometheus client library isn't modularized, so it is called an "unnamed module". How do I get access to the packages of such a library? I assume I add a dependency in my `module-info.java`?

This seems like a basic, common JPMS newbie issue, but after doing lots of searches I can't find the solution to this issue.

Comment: With some luck you can put prometheus on the module path, making it an automatic module.

Comment: Try java command line `--add-reads your.module=ALL-UNNAMED`.  If that works I'll document it in an answer.

Comment: Alternately try 'requires simpleclient' in your own module-info which is the automatic module name when one isn't defined otherwise.